# Updating (style.top) position of a floating menu with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a floating menu with JavaScript, is suppose to stay in the same position no mater if the user scrolls down or resize the window.

So far it is working just fine with X position. However, I can't find a way to make it stick to a position relative to the visible top of the window. The problem is when I scroll down the menu disappear because it keeps its distance related to the window size.

my code is:

```
    menuPosition : function (){
        var windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
        var windowWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
        var xPosFloatingMenu = (windowWidth) - (fMenuWidthGlobal + fMenuXPosGlobal);
        var yPosFloatingMenu = (windowHeight) - (windowHeight - fMenuYPosGlobal);
        document.getElementById("floating_menu").style.left = (xPosFloatingMenu) + "px";
        document.getElementById("floating_menu").style.top = (yPosFloatingMenu) + "px";


    },

    updateMenuPosition : function () {
        var menuPositionInterval = setInterval(gala.create.menuPosition,1);
    }
```

Is there a way to keep the menu position update relative to the **visible** top of the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the style properties of your floating_menu element on the window scroll Event .

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll

Comment: yes, but it messes with other fixed elements, plus this is part of a small library I'm doing.

Comment: So you have to update the style properties of your floating_menu element on the window scroll Event .  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll

Comment: yeah, that worked! sorry its really late around here, I just had to: fMenu.style.position = ("fixed"); on the function that creates the Menu Element. Thanks!